# Need to clear a function memory. jQuery running function too many times

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, memory-leaks

Initially, I had a problem that a click event was firing multiple times, but I have managed to overcome that with a probably over use of `unbind()` and `one()` as you'll see in my code below!

What I have here is some code which opens up a universally usable Modal window which I use for various things, including, in some cases a password form.

I don't think you need the HTML so I won't post that.

When a button, or an action causes the window to be required, I call the function like this:

```
showModalAlert(type, theWidth, theHeight, title, html, confirmThis, denyThis)
```

The first three variables determine how the window will look, `title` and `html` determine the content and `confirmThis` and `denyThis` are functions set immediately prior to calling this function and determine what the action should be if this is a `confirm` window and the `confirm` or `deny` buttons are press.

In the case of a `security` window, the confirm button is replace by a "sign it" button which submits a simple password form and returns a User Id from database. If a User Id is successfully returned, the script programatically presses the `confirm` button and in turn runs it's function as per the call to the inital opening of the modal window.

**My problem** is that if an incorrect password is entered, or a user cancels the window and then later without refreshing the browser window, re-enters the password correctly, the `confirmThis()` function is performed twice (or as many times as the incorrect password/cancel action was performed).

So, clearly, what it is doing is "remembering" the `confirmThis` function each time.

As I said, initially, the password success function was clicking `confirmIt` twice, copious use of `one()` has fixed this, it is now definitely only clicking `confirmIt` once, but it is still performing the function multiple time.

**How can I clear this function and ensure it is only performed once?**

The function from which I am calling the modal window looks like this:

```
    $('#saveDelivery').click(function () {
           function confirmIt() {
                formData = (JSON.stringify($('#delDetail').serializeObject()));
                saveData(formData);
                $('#saveDelivery').removeClass('centreLoader');
            };
            showModalAlert('security', '300px', '185px', 'Security!', 'You need to "Sign" this action.', confirmIt, '');
    });
```

It's simply a click on the `saveDelivery` element, the `confirmThis` function is declared at this point and submits an AJAX form

the actual `showModalAlert` function is below:

```
function showModalAlert(type, theWidth, theHeight, title, html, confirmThis, denyThis)        {

// stuff that opens the alert window \\

if (confirmThis == '') {
    $('#confirmIt').one('click', function () { $('#closeAlert').one('click').click(); });
} else {
    $('#confirmIt').one('click', function () { confirmThis(); $('#closeAlert').one('click').click(); });
};
if (denyThis == '') {
    $('#denyIt').one('click', function () { $('#closeAlert').one('click').click(); $('#signIt').unbind(); });
} else {
    $('#denyIt').one('click', function () { denyThis(); $('#closeAlert').one('click').click(); $('#signIt').unbind(); });
};   

if (type == "confirm") {
    $('.closeAlert, .signItForm').hide();
};
if (type == "alert") {
    $('.alertConfirm, .signItForm').hide();
};
if (type == "fixedAlert") {
    $('.closeAlert, .alertConfirm, .signItForm').hide();
};
if (type == "security") {
    $('.signItForm').show();
    $('.closeAlert').hide();
    $('#confirmIt').hide();
    $('#signIt').unbind().fadeTo('fast',1);
};
};

$('#signIt').live('click', function () {
var formData = (JSON.stringify($('.secureSign').serializeObject()));
var signitPwd = $('#signItpwd').val();
var jsonURL = "/jsonout/getdata.aspx?sql=SELECT id, password FROM users WHERE password ='" + signitPwd + "' LIMIT 1&output=json&usedb=new&labelName=any&fileName=";

$.getJSON(jsonURL, function (data) {
    if (data.length > 0) {
        $('.savingUserID').val(data[0].id);
        $('#confirmIt').one('click').click();
        $('#signIt').fadeTo('fast', 0);
        $('#confirmIt').show();
    } else {
        $('#signIt').fadeTo('fast', 0);
        $('#confirmIt').one('click').show();
        $('.closeAlert').show();
        $('.alertConfirm, .signItForm').hide();
        $('#alertTitle').html("Error!");
        $('#alertContent').css({ 'text-align': 'center' }).html("Password Denied");
    };
});
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From my understanding of `$.one`, it merely runs the event ONCE. If you bind it twice to the event, it will run twice instantaneously, but no more.

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/qCwMH/ (click the button, and it will run the event 4 times).

Each time you click saveDelivery, you are infact, binding another `$.one` event to `#confirmIt`.

What you could do is unbind your events from confirmIt and denyIt at the start of the modal function (i.e. `$('#confirmIt, #denyIt').unbind('click');`, and then you will assign them fresh each time that function is called, rather than building on top of them. Not ideal, as binding/unbinding uses more resources than other options, but just give that a try to start with perhaps?

Comment: Spot on! Excellent thanks, just adding that line to the top of the modal function fixed it. I'll try removing some of the other `unbind()` calls as well because they're probably not needed!

Comment: Sorted! Removed all other `unbind()` references and now it works perfectly! :D

Comment: Nice one :)! Glad I could help!